# Filtering pandas data frame with multiple conditions multiple times

Tags: pandas, dataframe, filter

I have this dataframe top100 (100 unique cities and states)

```
city            state   
Las Vegas       Nevada  
Fremont         California  
Boise City      Idaho   
Richmond        Virginia    
San Bernardino  California
....
```

and dataframe database (1,000,000 rows)

```
city            state          data
Las Vegas       Nevada         Las.Vegas.Nevada.2
Las Vegas       Nevada         Las.Vegas.Nevada.4
.....    
Boston          Massachusetts  Boston.Massachusetts.47
Boston          Massachusetts  Boston.Massachusetts.48
.....
Richmond        Virginia       Richmond.Virginia.34
....
```

How can I filter df using top100? Result would be the same format as database, but only with the top 100 cities in the top100 dataframe.
Here is what I have currently

```
def filter_city():
   # Initialize an empty dataframe to store result
   d = {'state': [], 'city':[], 'data':[]}
   df = pd.DataFrame(d)

   # Loop through each city in top 100
   for i in range(len(top100['city'])):
        tempCity = database[database['city'].str.contains(top100['city'][i]) & 
                             database['state'].str.contains(top100['state'][i])].copy()
        df = df.append(tempCity)
   return df
```

This function takes a really long time. I'm wondering if there is a faster way to do this?

Comment: Did you do `database.merge(top100, on=['city', 'state'])`?

Comment: Hi COLDSPEED, I just tried the above. The result is 7540 rows, whereas using my function, the result was 9073 rows (they are unique). I'm not sure why.

Comment: Edit: my function uses contains, so the result includes both 'Las Vegas' and 'North Las Vegas', for example. Your function is probably correct. Thank you!